# Soulmelds and Wild Shape

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, druid

Let's say, there is a Druid. He has some soulmelds shaped and really likes them, through he also likes his Wild Shape ability. He looks at his soulmelds, he looks at his Wild Shape and asks himself - "Am I able to combine them?"

Okay, here's the  question:
Can a Druid have active Soulmelds during Wild Shape, or are the Soulmelds being supressed for the duration?

The rules on Wild Shape say this:

> Any gear worn or carried by the druid melds into the new form and
>   becomes nonfunctional. When the druid reverts to her true form, any
>   objects previously melded into the new form reappear in the same
>   location on her body that they previously occupied and are once again
>   functional. Any new items worn in the assumed form fall off and land
>   at the druid's feet.

While the description on Soulmelds say this:

> Soulmelds are persistent magical constructions shaped from pure
>   incarnum—the power of souls living, dead, and yet unborn—fused with
>   the meldshaper’s own essence. They resemble both long-lasting spells
>   and magic items in many ways, but truly are neither. Once shaped, a
>   soulmeld takes on a solid physical form in the shape specifi ed for
>   that particular meld. A shaped soulmeld acts as a normal object that
>   might be worn, such as boots, armor, or a robe except for the
>   following: they cannot be removed from the individual wearing them,
>   they cannot be damaged except as specifi cally noted and they don’t
>   have a weight (though they can restrict movement, thus giving an armor
>   check penalty if applicable).

So, it looks like somewhat of a draw. Is there anything in RAW to solve this conundrum?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bound soulmelds take up magic-item slots, but are not items. They therefore do not get melded into the druid’s new form and do not become non-functional.

Note that *Magic Item Compendium* and (if I recall correctly, currently away from books) *Magic of Incarnum* have information on item slots/chakras for non-humanoid creatures. Most creatures have all of the item slots/chakras, though a few do not.

As a druid meldshaper, you may also want to consider the Share Soulmelds feat to give your Animal Companion some soulmelds as well.

Answer (score 1):

I would rule that if the animal form could wear an item of the same slot that the soulmeld takes it would be able to maintain it.

Comment: Note that, officially, there are rules about mapping item slots to different physiologies (e.g. a quadruped treats its forelimbs as Arms, and the feet on those limbs as Hands). Most creatures can wear most items.